# Windows Phone 8 - Geolocator PositionChanged listener dies after some time

Tags: c#, mobile, geolocation, windows-phone-8

I'm setting a PositionChanged listener in a Geolocator object with

```
var geolocator = new Geolocator();
geolocator.PositionChanged += Geolocator_PositionChanged;
```

It works fine for some time. But after some time without user interaction (+- 4 Hours) it stops receiving position changes, I think because WP8 simply kills it. This is maybe desired from ms, but this is horrible for my app model.

What I've done is to additionally set a PeriodicTask and send the position as well. And this runs with no problems, but if the user change his positions I'm unable to really track it.

The question is: Is there anyway to wake up this Geolocator without the need of user interaction? It can be via the PeriodicTask or even in the PositionChanged.

**I've tried already instantiating a new Geolocator already inside the PositionChanged delegate, but this doesn't work.**

Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does it happen too if you use GeoCoordinateWatcher class instead Geolocator?

Comment: @anderZubi Haven't tried that. It seems to me that MS wants to deprecate this interface anyway, no?

Comment: That's part of the .Net API, while the Geolocator class is part of the new WinPRT API. I don't know about the future intentions of Microsoft about the former, but if you are not sharing the code with a Windows Store app, you can use it.

Comment: @JoséLeal Do you find any solution for this problem??

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be some kind of GC that kills / disables the instance.

try to use `geolocator.addEventListener("statuschanged", onStatusChanged);`

and restart the object when status is `Windows.Devices.Geolocation.PositionStatus.disabled` or `Windows.Devices.Geolocation.PositionStatus.notAvailable`.

see [Geolocator.StatusChanged | statuschanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator.statuschanged) for more details.

Hope I helped

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but I've tried already, and it doesn't work that well.

Answer (score 1):

Are you specifying a timeout in your `GetGeopositionAsync` call? According to the last comment at the bottom of [this post](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/12/03/geoposition-advanced-tracking-scenarios-for-windows-phone-8.aspx), this code fixes an issue where the `GetGeopositionAsync` call was not returning. It may be related.

```
public Task GetCurrentPosition()
{

    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        if (_geolocator == null)
        {
           _geolocator = new Geolocator { DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High };
        }

        Geoposition geoposition = null;

        ManualResetEvent syncEvent = new ManualResetEvent(initialState: false);

        IAsyncOperation asyncOp = _geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();

        asyncOp.Completed += (asyncInfo, asyncStatus) =>
        {
           if (asyncStatus == AsyncStatus.Completed)
           {
               geoposition = asyncInfo.GetResults();
           }

           syncEvent.Set();

        };

        syncEvent.WaitOne();

        return geoposition.Coordinate;

    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably Garbage Collector finds it unused and kills or at least disables for power save.

Most of the hardware resources you are using have method called

```
addEventListener
```

It a way to inform that resource: "Hey! I'm want to get updates from you so don't die". And this is very common pattern to observe objects and get updates asynchroniusly.

Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern